# Is possible to reuse a already calculatesd column into a query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, computed-column

I have a query with complicated column, and I would like to use this column result in another column, for instance:

```
SELECT ( /* Complex query */ ) as myValue, if( myValue > 10, "OK" , "" ) from table;
```

but his query returns an error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'myValue' in 'field list
```

How can I reuse a already calculated field?

Comment: Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27790702/6521116

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use user-defined variable.

```
SELECT @temp := ( /* Complex query */ ) AS myValue, 
       IF ( @temp > 10, "OK" , "" )
FROM table;
```

Maybe server demands preliminary variable definition. If so,

```
SELECT @temp := ( /* Complex query */ ) AS myValue, 
       IF ( @temp > 10, "OK" , "" )
FROM table, (SELECT @temp := 0) dummy;
```

The documentation do not specified the order of output values calculations, but in practice it always matched the order they are written.

Comment: Can you tell when and why can server demand preliminary variable definition?

Comment: @Justinas What variable? UDV and GUDV do NOT need a definition. But their initial value is ALWAYS `NULL`. So if you do not init they by assigning some value you must consider this fact.

Comment: I signed up here just to give you my +1. THANKS!!!

Comment: Very good way of doing this without wrapping your query having correlated subqueries with another layer of select. Big thanks!

Comment: An important point when using this solution, in the select order, variable assignment should be done before it is used by another expression in the select list. Otherwise it uses the assigned value from previous row, resulting with wrong calculations.

Comment: @İlterKağanÖcal I have said that the output expressions evaluation matches their order in the query text. It seems to be the same... Real important point is that the rowsource in outer query must be single table, not 2 or more joined tables.

Answer (score 1):

I just learned that this is valid in MySQL (I am using version 8.0.21).

```
SELECT 1 AS X, 2 AS Y, (SELECT X + Y) AS Z
```

[image]

Therefore, you can try

```
SELECT /*Complex query*/ as myValue, 
(SELECT IF(myValue > 10, 'OK', '')) AS OK_if_higher_than_ten
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

My preference here is to use a sub-query, summarizing the results on the outside query:

```
    SELECT sq.myvalue, IF(sq.myvalue > 10 , "OK" , "") as `myresult`
    FROM ( 
        SELECT ( /* complex query */ ) as `myvalue` 
        FROM table
    ) sq;
```

An alternate approach repeats the complex query within the IF () statement rather than use `myvalue`

```
    SELECT 
        ( /*complex query*/ ) as `myvalue`
        , IF ( ( /*complex query*/ ) > 10 , "OK", "" ) as `myresult`
    FROM table;
```

Don't really care for that approach. The more complex the query (or calculation) the less desirable this alternative becomes over time.